# Creation/use of EpiServer properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, episerver, episerver-6

I'm working with EpiServer CMS 6 on the ASP .net 4.0 platform. I can create a property in Admin Mode just fine but is there a way to create properties in Visual Studio? (Not necessarily custom properties, just a simple String property for now). Am I right in saying the only way to do this would be by using Page Type Builder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the API to create PageTypes and PageDefinitions in code. [Here](http://world.episerver.com/FAQ/Items/How-to-update-page-types-with-a-new-property-in-code/) is a good starting point.

I would recommend you use PageTypeBuilder instead though, it offers many advantages over the API.